# Sharpe Ratio Calculation Best Practice

Tags: sharpe-ratio, performance-evaluation

For Sharpe ratio formula : $SR(s) = \frac{(x_s - r)}{\sigma_s}$ where for the time period under evaluation :

$x_s$ represents the average return of the portfolio

$r$ represents average return of the risk-free rate

is there a particular reason why do we use average return ? Wouldn't a best practice be to use the cumulative return over the time period under valuation ?

Comment: It is a standard practice in Statistics to compare the average of a variable to the standard deviation *of that variable*, and that is what is going on here. (It wouldn't make sense to have one thing in the numerator and the standard deviation of a different thing in the denominator, unless you adjusted for that somehow).

Comment: But in this case you can potentially have a situation that fund that have a negative cumulative return show positive SR and vice and versa. Don't seen to me a fair risk adjusted performance indicator.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Maybe you should clarify in your question what your concern is. (That the compound return could be of a different sign than the average return (or the sum of returns)).